# Print records from DataGridView

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

I'm creating a C# Windows application in which I have to print a fixed header and footer and the contents of a DataGridView in between them. Is it possible to print it?

Comment: More information would be useful in your question and a show of what you have found already or what your searches have turfed up even if it's nothing people can push you in the right direction with a specific search term!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Print` (Check out the documentation for [PrintPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188767.aspx) and PrintDocument) and `Drawing` API which is available with the .net framework.